# Is the DTFT of a sampled Gaussian a positive function?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

I have an infinite sequence $x_{n}$ for $n \in \mathcal{Z}$ which is a sampled Gaussian function $x_{n} = \exp(-n^2/a)$ with a > 0.
I need to check whether its DTFT $x(\theta) = \sum_{n \in \mathcal{Z}} x_{n} \exp(-i n \theta)$ is positive for all $\theta$, or sufficiently for all $\theta \in [0, 2 \pi)$ since it is periodic.
This function is real and can be expressed
$$x(\theta) = 1 + 2\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \exp(-n^2/a) \cos(n \theta)$$
due to the symmetry of the Gaussian function.
I suspect that it is positive but I'm not sure.
Can anyone help me prove or disprove it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y(t)$ be a continuos gaussian, let $u(t)=\sum \delta(t-Tk)$ be a train of pulses ([Dirac comb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb)). The values of your discrete function correspond to the product $x(t)=y(t) u(t)$, and the Fourier transform is the convolution - 
$$ X(w) = Y(w) \star U(W) =\sum_k Y(w-k/T) $$

But $Y(w)$ (Fourier transform of a centered Gaussian) is another Gaussian, hence positive. Hence, $X(w)$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks! What helped me to understand this was that $\sum_{n} x_{n} e^{-i n \theta} = \int x(t) [\sum_{n} \delta(t-n)] e^{-i t \theta} dt$.